# Create HTML newsletter source from Wordpress

Tags: html, newsletter

Is there a way to export certain posts into an HTML newsletter format that is suitable to email to subscribers?

I am thinking of something that allows me to select a certain amount of posts, etc and that then generates in-line HTML content with those posts in them in a format I can copy and paste into a newsletter management tool (i.e. mailchimp, campaigner, etc).

I've noticed that some mail providers like [mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/features/rss-to-email/), [aweber](http://www.aweber.com/blog-newsletters.htm), etc offers RSS to email, which looks pretty handy and might work - unfortunately my client is using campaigner.com which does not appear to offer this. Perhaps there is another straight forward way to generate an HTML email?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive and give more details? With the information you have given I only can say that you can make a query to get the content of the selected post and use wp_mail() to send the HTML email.

Comment: You're going to have the build the email from scratch dynamically if your client doesn't use a service that offers rss to email or something similar.  Alternatively, you can look into how those services actually implement rss to email, I bet there's some os projects you can fork to get started.  Quick google search: https://github.com/matthewkcarr/rss-to-email